# Getting error while installing lincache19 in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linecache

i am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.12 for my project.
when i run "bundle install", i get the following error.

```
Gem::InstallError: linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing linecache19 (0.5.12), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

i don't want to change my ruby version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the debugger gem instead of ruby-debug. Check out your gemfile and replace `gem "ruby-debug"` with `gem "debugger"`. From memory that's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `gem 'ruby-debug19'` with `gem 'ruby-debug'` worked for me.